# Create a Video File or PNG Sequence of Writing Out A Word

Tags: video

I  was wondering if there is a generator, or something out on the web where you type a word, and it would create a video file of it being written out.

I want to embed the file on a site, so when you go there the first time, it's not just loaded, it autoplays the video, so it starts to write the word and finishes writing the word.

How could I get something like this?

If there is no generator, could I accomplish this in photoshop? I'm not sure what to search

Thanks

Ermm Not sure Video Production is appropriate for this...

It can be done in flash,

Please migrate back to graphic design.

Comment: When you say "Write the word" what are you envisioning?

Comment: So imagine yourself writing the word "Test" on a piece of paper. You Start off with the T, You draw a line then cross the top, you move on to the E. etc.  In your case, you'd have a pencil or a pen.  In this case, I'd like it to just be magically appearing on the screen... I'll see if I can find an example

Comment: Not sure why this got migrated. You can try using the `flag` button to get a moderator's attention.

Comment: @Peege151 - this fits fine on video production.  It deals with animation, which is covered in video production.  Also, in addition to Flash, After Effects can also be used to accomplish this without needing to embed a flash animation.  I can reject the migration if you really want, but we do have very similar questions here.  (In fact, I'm pretty sure this is actually a dupe, but I need to go dig up the original.)

Comment: Might not quite be an exact dupe, but http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10814/how-do-i-create-a-video-of-typing-math-symbols is very related.  The big trick is that you have to manually establish stroke data somehow since fonts don't have stroke data.  That's normally done through masking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you need to to do this based on a raster image of a finished typeface design or if you are starting from scratch.
For both cases you can use flash like shown in the video you linked or you can use After Effects to have some more control over the look, doing this frame by frame is no that easy if you are after specific timing, instead you probably want to keyframe this.

After Effects is pretty great for this job, it has the so called "Stroke" effect where you can let After Effects draw a line based on a vector shape or "Masks" in After Effects.

You basically draw a vector path and the effect will draw along that path based on keyframes you set, you can also alter the line width of the "pencil" and have overall a much larger control of the look of the "writing".

Here is a small tutorial explaining the basics of the effect: